# How to upgrade Jquery to jquery1.4

Tags: jquery

I have a question I have a project asp.net mvc which is developed in jquery1.3.2.

I need to update whole project with jquery 1.4

can any one tell me the steps to do it this?

Comment: hey dude hows it going please use punctuation it really helps us to read your question k thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to drop the new file in place.  There are a few breaking changes, but you can either update the changes or download the backward compatibility plugin and use it.

Here is the info you need: http://jquery14.com/day-01#backwards

Comment: where do i need to download the jquery1.4? and can you tel me step by step process to do this
thanks